# VSCoode - running aws lambda fails with NodejsNpmBuilder:Resolver does not find node or npm runtime, although SAM does

Tags: aws-lambda, vscode-debugger

When running aws lambda with vscode run and debug I get Error: ValueError: Path resolution for runtime: nodejs18.x of binary: npm was not successful

buy when running with sam local start-api i don't get any errors

Os: Mac (happen also on AWS linux)

Answer (score 0):

The following trick by pass this issue:

1. cd /usr/local/bin
2. sudo mv sam sam.old
3. sudo vi sam
4. sudo chmod +x sam

for more info see: https://github.com/aws/aws-toolkit-jetbrains/issues/3063